# Python Scraper using BeautifulSoup '\n\n issue

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Good afternoon,

I am very new to Python and thought that a simple web scrape would be easy to grasp, however I am having an issue with the output of my query. the query is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://www.ebuyer.com/store/Components/cat/Processors-AMD/subcat/AMD-AM4-Ryzen-5')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)
week = soup.find(id='grid-view')
#print(week)
items = week.find_all(class_ = 'grid-item js-listing-product')
#print(items[0])
#print(items[0].find(class_='grid-item__title').get_text())
#print(items[0].find(class_='grid-item__ksp').get_text())
#print(items[0].find(class_='price').get_text())

product_description = [item.find(class_='grid-item__title').get_text() for item in items]
#sub_descriptions = [item.find(class_='grid-item__ksp').get_text() for item in items]
#price = [item.find(class_='price').get_text() for item in items]
print(product_description)
```

the output shows as:
['\n\n                AMD Ryzen 5 3600X AM4 CPU/ Processor with Wraith Spire Cooler\n            \n', '\n\n                AMD Ryzen 5 1600X 6 Core AM4 CPU/Processor\n            \n']

I would like to be able to remove the '\n\n from the text if possible?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = [item.a.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.select("h3.grid-item__title")]
    print(target)


main("https://www.ebuyer.com/store/Components/cat/Processors-AMD/subcat/AMD-AM4-Ryzen-5")
```

Output:

```
['AMD Ryzen 5 3600X AM4 CPU/ Processor with Wraith Spire Cooler', 'AMD Ryzen 5 1600X 6 Core AM4 CPU/Processor']
```